# File not found in python (WORDCLOUD)

Tags: python

When I try to run this it says file not found. Is there any misatkes I've made?

```
from wordcloud import  WordCloud
from wordcloud import STOPWORDS
import sys
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
os.chdir(sys.path[0])

text = open('pokemon.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8').read()
stop = STOPWORDS

print(stop)
```

Comment: Where is your pokemon.txt located?

Comment: on the same folder as the python file

Comment: Why do you think that `sys.path[0]` is the directory of python file? Print `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

Since your file is in the same folder as the Python program, use ./ before your pokemon.txt like this:

```
text = open('./pokemon.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8').read()
```

Comment: not working either same error